# HystrixRuntimeException : timed out

Tags: java, hystrix, netflix-zuul

I am getting this error:

> com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException:
>   getCatchmentsByAreaType timed-out and fallback failed.

When I try calling the same method though API it works. I don't know why!
I have set following properties in `ZuulApplication`:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=2000000
hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize=100
hystrix.threadpool.default.maxQueueSize=100
hystrix.threadpool.default.queueSizeRejectionThreshold=100
ribbon.IsSecured=true
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=2000000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=2000000
ribbon.maxAutoRetries=3
```

Comment: Can you enable hystrix debugging?

Comment: No, I can't. I am testing it on docker.

Comment: When you call the same method via API are you also running in a Docker container?

Comment: I solved this issue.  I have separated propertied for Hystrix and Zuul. Riibon properties I am using for Zuul and hystrix are for Hystrix only. I was just bit confused in those. Thanks to all!